# Comparing two Ansys Mechanical Model Trees

Tags: python-2.7, ansys

I want to compare two Ansys Mechanical Models and summarize the differences. For some cases it is sufficient to just compare the two ds.dat files with e.g. Notepad++. But different meshes make this comparison quickly confusing.

My idea is to export the tree of the two Models from
`ExtAPI.DataModel.Project.Model` to two dictionaries and than compare those. But I have difficulties keeping the structure.
When I try to iterate through all Children inspiried by [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-recursively-iterate-a-nested-Python-dictionary) with

```
#recursive function to iterate a nested dictionary       
def iterate(dictionary, indent=4):
    print '{'
    for child in dictionary.Children:
        #recurse if the value is a dictionary
        if len(child.Children) != 0:
            print ' '*indent + child.Name + ": " ,
            iterate(child, indent+4)
        else:
            print ' '*indent+ child.Name
            
    print ' '*(indent-4)+ '}'
```

I get the structure in a usable format:

```
iterate(Model) 
{
    Geometry:  {
        Part:  {
            Body1
        }
    ...
    }

    Materials:  {
        Structural Steel
    }
    Cross Sections:  {
        Extracted Profile1
    }
    Coordinate Systems:  {
        Global Coordinate System
    } ... }
```

But now I am strugling with replacing the print statement in the recursive function and keeping the structure from the model tree.

Comment: Would you please share the input file to be able to reproduce your results, thank you

Comment: If you execute the code sample in the ACT shell you will get comparable result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it into a dictionary comprehension:

```
def iterate(dictionary):
    return {
        child.Name: (iterate(child) if child.Children else None)
        for child in dictionary.Children
    }
```

The output will be:

```
{
    "Geometry":  {
        "Part":  {
            "Body1": None
        },
    ...
    },

    "Materials":  {
        "Structural Steel": None,
    }
    "Cross Sections":  {
        "Extracted Profile1": None,
    }
    "Coordinate Systems":  {
        "Global Coordinate System": None
    } ... }
```

You can use `pprint.pprint()` if you wish to format it nicely for presentation.